# Snapshot testing returning empty object with enzyme, jest and preact

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, preact

I am using combination of Enzyme and Jest to do snapshot testing in Preact project
`shallow` and `mount` are returning `ShallowWrapper{}` and `ReactWrapper{}` when used with jest and preact. I've used `enzyme-with-json` for serialization in `jest.config.js`, which returns the expected result, but `expect` fails when used with `toMatchSnapshot` since it compares it with Empty Object.

```
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Loader from './index';

describe('Loader Component', () => {
  it('should render correctly', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Loader />);
    console.log(component); // returns ShallowWrapper{}
    expect(shallowToJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

#### My setup :

```
"preact" : 10.3.3,
"jest": 26.0.1,
"jest-enzyme": 7.1.2
"enzyme-to-json": 3.5.0
"enzyme-adapter-preact-pure" : 2.2.0
```

Here's my setup file provided to Jest :

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import 'jest-enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-preact-pure';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Can anyone help me figure out what am I missing in this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using   `expect(toJson(component)).toMatchSnapshot();`
The first run will show something like "Snapshot generated" . Save the snapshot and next time onward it will compare and give errors if any.

Comment: Tried using toJson, same result. It shows  
     - Snapshot  -  1 (ShallowWrapper {})
    + Received  + 22 (JSX) 

I am assuming the matcher function isn't returning the required JSX.

Comment: There is another way to test whether it is working or not. just make a small jsx change in your component. And then run the test again. if it is working, it will show that '1 snapshot failed'

Comment: I wrapped the component inside the div, and got the same result. - Snapshot  -  1 (ShallowWrapper {})
    + Received  + 24 (JSX). The test did fail though, but it was failing earlier too.

Comment: This means your test case is working. If you still want to see the content of ShallowWrapper you can install a snapshot reading plugin in VS Code.